# Has the shift-key functionality while resizing objects changed in PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

In PowerPoint, holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when resizing an object such as a line should restrict the movement of the end point to be either vertical or horizontal. This is useful for resizing horizontal or vertical lines that you wish to stay horizontal and vertical.

In PowerPoint 2010 this appears to not always work. When I re-size a line while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> the movement is still restricted in direction, but the object snaps to some absurd length (i.e. hundreds of inches).

This behavior is not consistent (i.e. sometimes the object re-sizes as expected but sometimes it snaps to infinity), but the odd behavior appears unique to PowerPoint 2010.

**Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?**

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have enabled for Grid and Guides: go to View menu and click on the arrow below Ruler, Gridlines, Guides to show the Gird and Guides window.

You should uncheck *Snap objects to grid* option.

Comment: In PPT 2010, I found the *snap objects to grid* menu option by right-clicking in an open area (i.e. I could not figure out how to access this option via the ribbon as there was no pop-out box arrow below the check boxes to activate the grid and ruler). *Snap to grid* was already unchecked, but I experimented with every combination of that option and *snap to objects*--nothing fixed the problem.